# recursive printf of binary tree elements

Tags: c, binary-tree, kernighan-and-ritchie

I've come back to K&R in order to read one chapter, and noticed an example I had previously omitted.
The chapter covers the topic of a binary tree data type. I understand storing new entries in the nodes, but printing function gives confuses me. Why is printing of the left part called first?

Would it work if `printf` would be the first command in function, followed by left and right?

If not - why then?

```
/* treeprint: in-order print of tree p */
void treeprint(struct tnode *p)
{
    if (p != NULL) {
        treeprint(p->left);
        printf("%4d %s\n", p->count, p->word);
        treeprint(p->right);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inorder#Depth-first_traversal

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Descending the left side first, then printing the node itself, then descending the right side, is what makes this operation *in-order* tree traversal.  If you moved the `printf` before the left descent, as you suggest, that would make it *pre-order* traversal.  And if you did both descents first, that would be *post-order*.  All three possibilities visit all of the nodes, but in three different orderings.

Consider the simple tree

```
  *
 / \
a   +
   / \
  b   c
```

If you traverse this tree in pre-order you get

```
* a + b c
```

In-order,

```
a * b + c
```

Post-order,

```
a b c + *
```

Which one of these possibilities you *want* depends on what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it would "work". You'd just get a different ordering on the output. You could also print the node *after* printing both child nodes. (And imagine if you had a tree with multiple children, not just two.)

The real question is whether the *values* of the tree nodes obey any special rules, and thus whether any particular traversal order is particularly meaningful. For example, for a [binary search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) the left-self-right order prints out the values in sort order.

Answer (score 0):

You can walk through a binary tree in different ways: Pre-order, In-order and Post-Order.

The printf could be an entirely different procedure (computation of node data). Some problems require different ways of walking on a tree, for example, if you're balancing a binary tree, you would calculate the balance factor after visiting both child trees.

So, the printf can be thought as a place holder for other kind of procedures/functions to deal with different kinds of problems.